# RE:Monero GUI - "Start Mining" greyed out

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mining, blockchain, daemon, wallet

Excuse the noobness.

I have installed Monero GUI Wallet on a persistent TAILS OS USB bootable drive.

I have downloaded the Monero Blockchain and fully synhronized the Wallet and Daemon. All working fine.I used this guide (https://czechmonero.cz/monero-full-node-on-tails).

The guide advised to setup a REMOTE NODE 127.0.0.1:17600 which I have (Even though I have downloaded the full blockchain).

I go to ADVANCED - MINING but the option to START MINING is greyed out and I cannot start the process. I know it says "Mining is only available on local daemons" but anyone have any idea how to start the mining process wtih this setup - or is it not possible?

Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Don't think you can mine on a remote node.  Even if on your own LAN.  Maybe drop the, what sounds like, self hosted remote node? (127.0.0.1 is the TAILS machine). You are remote'ing to yourself.

Comment: You need to start mining in the daemon (monerod) directly through `start_mining <address>`